# Scala what does the "def function = Type {" mean?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play 2.x and found the following syntax in action handlers e.g.

```
object Application extends Controller { 
    /**
     * Index action handler
     */
    def index = Action { implicit request => 
      Ok(Json.obj("one" -> "two"))
    }
}
```

Here I understand everything except the `= Action` which is not the type of the function, because the function return type is `play.api.mvc.Result`. So what does the `= Action` mean?

To make the understanding worse I now introduced authentication and based on examples changed my Application to:

```
object Application extends Controller with Secured { 
    /**
     * Index action handler
     */
    def index = IsAuthenticated { username => implicit request => 
      Ok(Json.obj("one" -> "two"))
    }
}
```

This works but why the `Action` is no longer necessary? was it necessary at all? how can I combine several of these types (whatever they mean): `Action` or `DBAction`, `IsAuthenticated` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now thanks to a colleague I understood what it is. That syntax that simply means returning an object, in this case an object of type `Action` and the action takes as constructor argument a function that takes as input a Request and returns a `SimpleResult`, it can be rewritten as e.g.

```
object Application extends Controller { 
    /**
     * Index action handler
     */
     def index : Action[AnyContent] = { 
         Action(implicit request => Ok(Json.obj("one" -> "two")))
     }
 }
```

What makes it actually confusing is that in Scala they can switch between parenthesis and curly brackets somewhat indistinctly. Therefore makes it tricky to realize it is not a function body what I was looking at but a constructor parameter to an action (which is an anonymous function)

Comment: But the return type is not `Action[AnyContent]`, it's `Future[Result]`. It isn't a constructor for `Action`, because there is no `Action` class, it's a trait. `Action(...)` is just scala syntactic sugar for `Action.apply`, which can return anything (in this case `Future[Result]`).

Answer (score 2):

`Action` is not a type, it is a function. If it were a type the signature for `index` would look like

`def index: Action = { implicit request =>`

Notice the addition of the `:` and the location of the `=`

The relevant [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaActions) states an Action is a

> function that handles a request and generates a result to be sent to
>   the client

As you noticed you are returning a `play.api.mvc.Result`

Comment: The method that is being called is `def apply(=>Result)` on the [`Action` companion object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action$).

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't answer my question ... what's the purpose of Action there? why it "works" without it? simply replacing it by `IsAuthenticated` and how can several be combined?

Comment: You're calling a function that takes in a `play.api.mvc.Request` and returns a `play.api.mvc.Result` (as @ggovan pointed out this is the Action companion object's apply method in this particular case). You can replace this with anything else that also takes in a `Request` and returns a `Result` (or multiple ones chained) but I wouldn't say "it 'works' without it." That's like saying if `2 + 2 = 4` why does `2 - 2 = 0` "work" without an addition sign.